# Charles proxy - content on app not displayed on device

Tags: windows, configuration, charles-proxy

I managed to successfully install the Charles proxy on my Windows 10. I have also successfully installed the certificates on my devices. However when I use the app that I want to test, none of the content is returned, I can see the URLs being called on Charles. If I use the same app on my windows machine, the content is returned. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community that can help you with questions about programming and software development in general. If you need help configuring and using a particular piece of software, please consult the appropriate documentation. This might be a good place to start: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing the call to the URLs that you expect, but not the content you're expecting, it may be SSL Proxying hasn't been enabled for those URLs.
If you're seeing encrypted data instead of your expected content, follow the instructions below to enable SSL Processing.

But first, something to keep in mind:

**Be judicious when enabling SSL Proxying. It will allow unencrypted data to be sent and received**, which is risky.
Don't enable it for any host that deals with sensitive/private information.
The screenshots I've included appear to show that I'm allowing SSL Proxying for google-dot-com, but this is for illustrative purposes only (which I did in order to avoid sharing any proprietary information within my company's service calls).

Instructions for enabling SSL Proxying:

1. Select the line for which you'd like decrypted data:
   [image: Selected Call]
2. Right-click and select "Enable SSL Proxying"

[image: Selecting SSL Proxying from right-click menu]

You may also manually add hosts via the this method:
Toolbar > Proxy Settings > SSL Proxying Settings

Please note:

This answer contains the solution that I have given to my work peers when they said they "weren't seeing content" (but it was actually just encrypted). If there is NO content at all, this answer may not resolve your issue. I'd have liked to reply to the original question for more details, but my reputation is too low to comment.

Hoping this helps, and if not, any additional details and/or screenshots of what you're seeing under the request/response may help to get you a helpful answer.